# Magento Admin Url Messed up

Tags: magento-1.9

I updated "Use Custom Admin URL" by mistake.
after that my Admin page is showing 404 and Css paths also take `/newpath/../../cssname.css`

I checked core_config_data and set admin/url/use_custom to 0.
but still problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it. i messed up `web/unsecure/base_url`